# Jupyter nbconvert LaTex Export Theme

Tags: python, css, latex, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I am using Jupyter Notebook nbconvert (Save as menu) to export as pdf via Latex. However, the pdf file is not in a good shape. For example, some wide tables are shown well. I would prefer to have a box for tables to be resized to the width of the page. Is there any style, template that I can use to have nice reports and how I may ask nbconverter to use that style?

Here is the Latex output:

[image]

I would like something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like Pandas gained a `._repr_latex_()` method in version 0.23. You'll need to set `pd.options.display.latex.repr=True` to activate it.

Without latex repr:
[image: Without latex repr]
With latex repr:
[image: With latex repr]

Check out the [options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/options.html#options-available) to get the formatting close to what you want. In order to match your desired output exactly, you'll need to use a custom latex template.

---

Edited to provide more information on templates:

[Start here](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html) for general information about templates. You can create a `.tplx` file in the same path as your notebook and specify it as the template when running `nbconvert` from the command line: `!jupyter nbconvert --to python 'example.ipynb' --stdout --template=my_custom_template.tplx`. Alternatively, you can specify a default template to use when exporting as Latex via the menu by modifying the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file in your `~.jupyter` directory. If this file doesn't exist already, you can generate it by running the command `jupyter notebook --generate-config` from the command line. I have my template sitting in the `~/.jupyter` directory as well, so I added the following to my `jupyter_notebook_config.py`:

```
# Insert this at the top of the file to allow you to reference
# a template in the ~.jupyter directory
import os.path
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.expanduser("~") + '/.jupyter')
# Insert this at the bottom of the file:
c.LatexExporter.template_file = 'my_template' # no .tplx extension here
c.LatexExporter.template_path = ['.', os.path.expanduser("~") + '/.jupyter'] # nbconvert will look in ~/.jupyter
```

To understand a bit about how the templates work, start by taking a look at [null.tplx](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/master/nbconvert/templates/latex/skeleton/null.tplx). The line `((*- for cell in nb.cells -*))` loops over all the cells in the notebook. The `if` statements that follow check the type of each cell and call the appropriate block.

The other templates extend `null.tplx`. Each template defines (or redefines) some of the blocks. The hierarchy is `null->display_priority->document_contents->base->style_*->article`.

Your custom template should probably extend `article.tplx` and add some Latex commands to the header that sets up the tables the way you want. Take a look at [this blog post](http://blog.juliusschulz.de/blog/ultimate-ipython-notebook) for an example of setting up a custom template.

Comment: Great! Where should I leave the template? What is the format of the template, tex file? Any sample?
@butterwagon

Answer (score 1):

Any setting that change the table size to fit it in the width of the page?
Latex code is something like this: `\resizebox*{\textwidth}{!}{%`

[image]

Comment: I also have the same problem and I opened a new question regarding this issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60729821/how-to-show-all-dataframe-table-columns-for-wide-tables-while-exporting-as-pdf)